# Using ng-show in Angular with an OR and NOT condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

Is it possible to use ng-show based on two conditions, well I guess in this case 3 conditions. I know i can probably do this with a function or directive but it is when loading the view and propagating data into dynamically generated form elements using ng-repeat. It would just be easier at this point to add the condition to the ng-show as the actual input is not marked invalid and the form itself will still submit as valid. When the form first loads the last element in the dynamically created form displays the error message as if it is invalid until $touched = true and the $veiwValue changes.

To keep it simple, my ng-show looks like this:

```
<div class="list-help-block" ng-messages="emails_form.email.$error" ng-show="emails_form.email.$dirty || emails_form.email.$invalid">
    <div ng-messages-include="/app/views/messages.html" ></div>
</div>
```

This displays the error messages fine on an invalid entry and on error when form is submitted. However it also displays the error message (which there shouldn't even be an error) when the form loads. And just on the last input dynamically added to the form.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
ng-show="emails_form.email.$dirty || emails_form.email.$invalid NOT mails_form.email.$pristine"
```

I don't even know if that's possible or if it may be possible to call a function to fix the validation once the view is fully loaded and the data has been added to the model. Any suggestions?

Here's the whole section that is used for this:

```
<div ng-repeat="emails in info.instructor.instructor_emails">
    <ng-form name="emails_form" novalidate>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-label">
            <span ng-show="info.instructor.instructor_emails.length==1">@</span>
            <span ng-show="info.instructor.instructor_emails.length>=2"><a ng-click="updateRemoveEmail($index)"><i class="fi-x"></i></a></span>
        </span>                                             
    <input ng-class="{ notvalid: submitted && emails_form.email.$invalid }"type="email" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com" name="email" ng-model="emails.email" ng-required="info.instructor.instructor_emails.length>=2"/>
    </div>
    <div class="list-help-block" ng-messages="emails_form.email.$error" ng-if="!emails_form.email.$pristine && (emails_form.email.$dirty || emails_form.email.$invalid)">
    <div ng-messages-include="/app/views/messages.html" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<div class="list-help-block" ng-messages="emails_form.email.$error" ng-if="  (!emails_form.email.$pristine && (emails_form.email.$dirty || emails_form.email.$invalid)) || (emails_form.email.$pristine && emails_form.email.$error.required) ">
    <div ng-messages-include="/app/views/messages.html" ></div>
</div>
```

It's ugly but does what I need it to do. Thanks @developer033 for pointing me in the right direction. Next time I'll use a custom directive for all this junky code

Answer (score 3):

As a suggestion, I'd recommend you to use [**`ngIf`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead of `ngShow` as a good practice.

As per I understood your `NOT`, It should work:

```
ng-if="!emails_form.email.$pristine && (emails_form.email.$dirty || emails_form.email.$invalid)"
```

Comment: That works when you load the view the first time, but kills the display of a required error when you add a new input dynamically. To see the basic idea on how I'm adding the fields check out [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Xh0o82N1xQc7Qi5Mhfe?p=preview) Maybe that would help understand how I'm doing this.

Comment: When the user press `Add Email`, what are you expecting?

Comment: I want it to add a field which needs to validate and show the validation error message, they are also $pristine = true when added to the form so the ng-if as above keeps those fields from showing the validation message when those fields are validated, the basic code to add and remove the fields is found at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Xh0o82N1xQc7Qi5Mhfe?p=preview) I would post all my code but it's a little convoluted to be honest

Comment: In a nutshell, after the user add a email you want to show the message, is it?

Comment: Yes as soon as the user adds an email field I want the required message to display, just not the email error when the form loads

Comment: It's working man.. you just commited the mistake in `<ng-form="sub_form">`.. change it to: `<ng-form name="sub_form">`. Also you're on `ngRepeat` you have to use another syntax to bind your names/`ngModel` and if you want to display required message.. you have first to have one required message and you don't.

Comment: This is the correct way to use it: http://plnkr.co/edit/bfY0aCohT6JWDaNjYzLQ?p=preview

Comment: I forgot that's how that plunkr had it coded, i already fixed that in my code. I posted the whole block of code within the ng-repeat above and all the add email button does is push an object into the $scope feeding these dynamically added fields

Comment: as you can tell i'm new to angular, I'm mainly a PHP coder doing all this server side, i'm trying to improve performance by doing most of the business logic client side through a RESTful API that is only used to fetch and put data to the database server side

Comment: Your plunker pretty much does it except i want to show the required error message as soon as the email is added